# Zend 2 removing https from iframe

Tags: php, iframe, zend-framework2

I'm trying to include an iframe into a Zend 2 view. No matter what I do the frame is displayed http. I have tried using the path like this

```
echo '<iframe src="/path/to/iframe.php">';
```

and

```
echo '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/path/to/iframe.php">';
```

Both show on the site as

http://example.com/path/to/file.php

It seems Zend is stripping out the https and replacing it with http.

I'm sure this is something simple. I've searched high and low and cannot find an answer. This is causing a problem as it is flagging up mixed content.

Comment: How do you generate the url/iframe, can you please provide the relevant section of your code?

Comment: I have edited my question to include this. Apologies for not making this clear

Comment: in this case, I don't think that zend does anything with the url/iframe, have you tried it in a simple html/php file to ensure it hasn't another reason?

Comment: You are correct! It wasn't zend doing this it was the contents of the iframe (single page php image gallery). I didn't think to create a simple file to check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with Zend but with the iframe itself.

Single page php gallery (which was the contents of the iframe) redirects to http.

Lesson learned here, always check that it is what you think causing the problem